Mistake in Conditional Probability/Betting question approach
Problem
You and your friend draw a number from [0, 100] uniformly at random. You are given the option to redraw your number once you've drawn the first time. Whoever has the higher number wins 20$. The loser gets nothing. How much would you pay to play this game?
My Approach
We know from a previous part that the expected value of the game without the redraw option is 10$. Now that we have the redraw option, we can formulate a strategy: if, on the first draw, I receive something less than 50, I will redraw because I would expect 50 on the redraw. So if I get something less than 50, we are playing the original game all over again. And if I draw something more than 50, I will stick with that.
$E($new game$)=P($probability my draw is less than 50$)\cdot E($original game$)+P($probability my draw is greater than 50$)\cdot E($new game$)$
I'm having trouble determining the last quantity. Here is one way I thought about it:
$P($my number is x and their number is less than x$)=\int_{50}^{100} P($my draw = x$)P($their draw less than x$)=\int_{50}^{100} dx \frac{x}{100}$
But this yields a number greater than one.
EDIT:
I just thought of a nice way to do this.
$P($I win | my draw > 50$)=1 \cdot P($their draw < 50$)$ + $\frac{1}{2}P($their draw > 50$)$ = 0.75. But I would still like to understand where I'm going wrong with the integral approach.

What happens if both players have the same number?

I assumed I wouldn't have to worry about that in the continuous case. Is that not true?

Keeping in mind that it has been over 50 years since I took a single Elementary Probability course, my speculation is that you are right.

If both you and your friend are allowed to redraw, then due to symmetry the expected value remains $10$$

That's true. In this case, you are the only one who is able to avail the benefits of this option.

Assume that the draw is continuous (then you can actually assume wlog that you draw from $[0,1]$), and that only you have this option.
Since you want to get the number as large as possible, and the median is $1/2$, you will redraw if and only if your first number is less than $1/2$ (probability of which is also $1/2$). Conditioned on having drawn second time, you result is $U[0,1]$, but if you decided not to draw, it means your result was $U[1/2,1]$. Hence the cdf of $X$, the number you ended up with, is a mixture of this two cdfs:
$$
F_X(x)=\frac12 \left[ x 1_{0\le x\le 1}+(2x-1) 1_{\frac12\le x\le 1}\right]
$$
for $x\le 1$.
You lose if $X<Y$ where $Y$ is $U[0,1]$, so the probability of losing is
$$
\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\int_0^1 F_X(y) \cdot1\mathrm{d}y=\frac38.
$$
Hence your expectation of this game is $0\cdot\frac38+20\cdot\frac58=12.5$,
As a result, it's worth paying upto \$12.5 for the game.


You have to multiply $\frac38$ with $0$, not with $-20$.

This is right up to this comment. Just multiply with 0 instead, and you're right.

Corrected, I missed that if you lose the opponent gets $20 not from you.
